# Search issues on GitLab with REST API by multiple labels - any label should result in a match

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-api

I need to pull issues from GitLab that match any of the labels. For instance I only want to see issues labelled as "`type:bug`" and also have one of severity labels "`severity:critical`" or "`severity:high`".

If I construct my request as

```
curl --header "PRIVATE-TOKEN: my-token-XXX" "https://gitlab-url.org/api/v4/issues?sort=desc&order_by=created_at&labels=type:bug&labels=severity:critical,severity:high"
```

it will try to find issues that have labels BOTH "severity:critical" and "severity:high" resulting in empty list. I'd like to pull issues that have at least one label of the two.

So far I haven't found an example of how to achieve that.

Answer (score 0):

Seems it's [not possible](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/issues.html#list-issues), at least not with this endpoint. Maybe there's an open issue in the [gitlab issues](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/) (and if not, you can open one).

It says about the `labels` query parameter:

```
Comma-separated list of label names, issues must have all labels to be returned.
None lists all issues with no labels. Any lists all issues with at least one label.
No+Label (Deprecated) lists all issues with no labels. Predefined names are case-insensitive.
```

You could use a workaround to just get all the issues and search the labels in your program.

```
curl --header "PRIVATE-TOKEN: my-token-XXX" "https://gitlab-url.org/api/v4/issues?sort=desc&order_by=created_at&labels=Any"
```

Then you can access

```
result_of_curl[i]["labels"]  # ==["bug", "severity:high"]
```

and do anything you want with that.

The object returned is something like

```
[
  {
    "id":9999,
    "iid":1,
    "project_id":999,
    "title":"Flying pigs needed",
    "description":"Pigs needed that can fly",
    "state":"closed",
    "created_at":"2023-07-25T13:00:00.000Z",
    "updated_at":"2023-11-15T15:57:49.553Z",
    "closed_at":"2023-11-15T15:57:49.540Z",
    "closed_by":{
      ...
    },
    "labels":[
      "bug",
      "severity:high"
    ],
    ...
  },
  ...
]
```